# Generate big cube of blocks

Tags: java, libgdx

I used LibGDX with Java. I trying create boxes in cube.

This code is not work, it create 9 cubes in line, not in cube..

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                table[i] = modelBuilder.createBox(2f, 2f, 2f, new Material(),
                        VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);
                table2[i] = new ModelInstance(table[i]);

                table2[i].transform.setToTranslation(i * 2, j * 2, 0f);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that with this piece of code, all you get is 9 boxes in a row (horizontally), but what you'd like to get is 10 rows of boxes, where each row has 10 boxes?

Comment: Yes! If i have 100 cubes, i must have 10 rows of 10 cubes. analogously

Comment: I'm confused. It seems that a _box_ is a cube in itself (of _side_ 2), and if so, do you want to create a _square_, made out of 10 rows of 10 such _boxes_ each (10^2 boxes), or a _cube_, made out of 10 such _squares_ (which would amount to 10^3 boxes)?

Comment: I have created 100 cubes in 10 rows of 10 cube in one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with LibGDX, but it seems like the boxes that belong to row indices 0 to 8 are created, but discarded, and only the last row of index 9 is kept. Assuming that what you want is a square made out of 10^2 boxes, try something like this in your inner loop:

```
table[j][i] = modelBuilder.createBox(...);
table2[j][i] = new ModelInstance(table[j][i]);

table2[j][i].transform.setToTranslation(j * 2, i * 2, 0f);
```

(Naturally, for each `table[j]` there needs to be a `table[j][i]` for i = 0 to 9, so you need to declare that elsewhere.)

Comment: @airmediapl Cool. Please up-vote my answer, so that others with similar issues can see more quickly that it's a useful answer.